# Ionic - Http error with andriod emulator using Capacitor?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, httprequest, ionic4, capacitor

I am using .Net Core Web API in the Back End and of course Allow Any Origin in Cors:

[image]

And I call it from ionic 4 project using httpClient and it is worked perfectly in Development mode on any browser like Chrome or Firefox..

**But when Build it as a native  Android using Capacitor and run on Emulator  I have this error:**

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/login-login-module-es2015.js - Line 155 -
Msg: Http failure response for http://zawag.azurewebsites.net/api/auth/login/: 0 Unknown Error
```

I don't know if is it because using API without SSL Certificate or What?

If so or not, what is the solution?